# how to call a function in vue when navigating way from route?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to call a function that clears local storage when the user navigates away from the current page. How would I accomplish this? I tried using the `destroyed()` lifecycle hook but it did not work. Would using `beforeRouteLeave()` be a good solution and how would I implement that in my routes file?

my route:

```js
  {
    path: "/success",
    name: "Success",
    component: () =>
      import("../views/Success.vue"),
  },
```

my hook on the success page as it currently stands:

```js
  destroyed() {
    window.localStorage.removeItem("intent");
  },
```

what i tried with `beforeRouteLeave`

```js
  beforeRouteLeave: function(to, from, next) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem("intent");
    next();
  },
```

my mounted hook

```js
let intent = window.localStorage.getItem(intent);
    // const product = window.localStorage.getItem(product);

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/pay/confirm", {
        params: {
          intent: intent
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.status);
        if (res.data.status == "succeeded") {
          console.log(res.data.status);
          this.confirmPayment();
        } else {
          this.paid = false;
        }
        console.log(this.item);
      });
  },
```

Comment: How exactly is `destroyed` hook not working for you? If you actually navigated away from it, this particular hook should fire, as well as `beforeRouteLeave`.

Comment: it may have something to do with my mounted hook, ill add it in to the question. But the way i see it, the get request should not go through when navigating back to the page since intent has been removed from local storage upon navigating away. when I log out localStorage in my console, Intent is not in the object. So i don't understand why my get request is still going through.

Comment: To clarify, when you say "when the user navigates away from the current page," are they navigating *away* from `Success.vue`, or *to* it?

Comment: they are naivigating away from success.vue to any other route in my site.

Comment: @Ren There doesn't seem to be any `if` check that would prevent the GET requests on `mounted`.

Comment: @YomS. but the get request should return empty if the intent param is not provided. I can add my back end code too to that request.

Comment: @Ren What does this "button" you're talking about do in the first place, does it router `push` to some other route? If so, do you attach any additional params or queries alongside it? We need more context to help you. Please be more specific.

Comment: Ok, @YomS. After looking at the backend code, I narrowed down the issue, the params are not being passed to the backend with the get request, and there is an issue with the route itself. I am currently trying to fix it and hopefully, that should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try set (global/page) watcher for you, which will be do something when you route object changed

```
watch:{
    $route: function(to, from){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mayby you can use the beforeDestroy() hook instead of the destroyed() hook.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).